# How I can create a button using javascript to delete an action (Facebook Open Graph)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

the code of tutorial is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function postCook()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook?recipe=http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html',
        'post',
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
```

I need to create a button in the same way but to remove the option of the timeline.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this can only work if you have the Action ID of the item you want to delete. So if you set up your button as shown below, you could use this:

```
//Button code
<button onclick="deleteCook(ActionID)">Delete Cook </button>

 <script type="text/javascript">   
function deleteCook(ActionID) {



            FB.api(ActionID, 'delete', function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');

              } else {
                 alert('Cook action was deleted');
                          }
            });

                                               });
           }
</script>
```